# Magento Add url link to open a specific product tab

Tags: magento, tabs, product

Magento 1.7.0.0

ok i'm using the product tabs that are available in the modern theme. I've added a custom tab to add reviews as a tab [sucess].

Now where it says:

'Be the first to review this product'
i want this link to go to the tab on that page and not go off to the reviews page.

i realise i need to some javascript but it's just i can't work out how to call a tab.

any ideas?

thanks.
Andy.

Comment: Switched to working with jquery-ui, i already had jquery installed so yes it's another lot of loading of a js library but at present there was no easy way round this :( bring on Magento 2 when it goes over to jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code looks like this in tabs.phtml:

```
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

and then adding:
jquery-ui-tabs.js and the relevant .css

Answer (score 2):

if you already using jQuery... you could just simply "hack" it out like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#addreview").attr("href", "#review-form");
        $("#addreview").click(function(){
            $(".product-tabs").children("li").removeClass("active");
            $("#product_tabs_reviews").addClass("active");
            $(".product-tabs-content").css("display", "none");
            $("#product_tabs_reviews_contents").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
```

be aware to change the selector according to your own markup